# I built a GUI in python using pyQt but it is not running correctly. Other people are able to run it correctly. What should I try?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm developing a GUI control program for a robot I've been working on, and I cannot get the app to run properly on my PC. None of the button.clicked() signals are triggering properly, and neither the self.value_box.setValue() nor the self.value_box.setMaximum() are being called.

I posted this in the python developer forums yesterday night, but a hack has left that forum compromised. (Do not go there, btw) Before the forum was attacked, someone told me that the code was running properly inside their dev environment. Can anybody give troubleshooting suggestions?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.serial_active = False
        self.cv_active = False
        self.pid_set = False
        self.pid_active = False

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.refresh_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.connect_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.comms_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.video_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.video_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.comms_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pid_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_val_out = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_val_out = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.detected_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ball_detected_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.p_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.i_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.d_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.p_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.i_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.d_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.pid_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_2 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.control_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pitch_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.roll_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pitch_out_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.roll_out_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(self)
        self.openGLWidget = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.refresh_button.clicked.connect(self.refresh_button_clicked)
        self.connect_button.clicked.connect(self.connect_button_clicked)
        self.video_button.clicked.connect(self.video_button_clicked)
        self.pid_button.clicked.connect(self.pid_button_clicked)
        self.control_button.clicked.connect(self.control_button_clicked)

        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(980, 779)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.refresh_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 640, 93, 30))
        self.refresh_button.setObjectName("refresh_button")
        self.connect_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 600, 93, 30))
        self.connect_button.setObjectName("connect_button")
        self.comms_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 600, 93, 25))
        self.comms_box.setObjectName("comms_box")
        self.video_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 600, 101, 30))
        self.video_button.setObjectName("video_button")
        self.video_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 570, 111, 19))
        self.video_title.setObjectName("video_title")
        self.comms_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 570, 111, 19))
        self.comms_title.setObjectName("comms_title")
        self.pid_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 570, 101, 19))
        self.pid_title.setObjectName("pid_title")
        self.x_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 670, 81, 19))
        self.x_label.setObjectName("x_label")
        self.y_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 700, 81, 19))
        self.y_label.setObjectName("y_label")
        self.x_val_out.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 670, 91, 19))
        self.x_val_out.setObjectName("x_val_out")
        self.y_val_out.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 700, 91, 19))
        self.y_val_out.setObjectName("y_val_out")
        self.detected_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 640, 111, 19))
        self.detected_label.setObjectName("detected_label")
        self.ball_detected_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 640, 68, 19))
        self.ball_detected_val.setObjectName("ball_detected_val")
        self.p_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 640, 68, 19))
        self.p_label.setObjectName("p_label")
        self.i_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 670, 68, 19))
        self.i_label.setObjectName("i_label")
        self.d_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 700, 68, 19))
        self.d_label.setObjectName("d_label")
        self.output_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 570, 121, 19))
        self.output_title.setObjectName("output_title")
        self.x_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 640, 68, 19))
        self.x_out_label.setObjectName("x_out_label")
        self.p_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 640, 72, 25))
        self.p_value_box.setObjectName("p_value_box")
        self.p_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.p_value_box.setValue(10)
        self.i_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 670, 72, 25))
        self.i_value_box.setObjectName("i_value_box")
        self.i_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.i_value_box.setValue(10)
        self.d_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 700, 72, 25))
        self.d_value_box.setObjectName("d_value_box")
        self.d_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.d_value_box.setValue(10)
        self.pid_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 600, 93, 30))
        self.pid_button.setObjectName("pid_button")
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 640, 160, 20))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 670, 160, 20))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_2")
        self.control_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 600, 101, 30))
        self.control_button.setObjectName("control_button")
        self.y_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 670, 68, 19))
        self.y_out_label.setObjectName("y_out_label")
        self.pitch_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 600, 68, 19))
        self.pitch_label.setObjectName("pitch_label")
        self.roll_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 650, 68, 19))
        self.roll_label.setObjectName("roll_label")
        self.pitch_out_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 620, 68, 19))
        self.pitch_out_val.setObjectName("pitch_out_val")
        self.roll_out_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 670, 68, 19))
        self.roll_out_val.setObjectName("roll_out_val")
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 960, 540))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(self)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Stewie Control Page"))
        self.refresh_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))
        self.connect_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.video_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Video"))
        self.video_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Video Controls"))
        self.comms_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Serial Controls"))
        self.pid_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PID Controls"))
        self.x_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X Position:"))
        self.y_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y Position:"))
        self.x_val_out.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Yet Set"))
        self.y_val_out.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Yet Set"))
        self.detected_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ball Detected?:"))
        self.ball_detected_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "No"))
        self.p_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "P:"))
        self.i_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I:"))
        self.d_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D:"))
        self.output_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output Controls"))
        self.x_out_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X_value"))
        self.pid_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set P,I,D"))
        self.control_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Control"))
        self.y_out_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y_value"))
        self.pitch_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pitch:"))
        self.roll_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Roll:"))
        self.pitch_out_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Set"))
        self.roll_out_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Set"))

    def perform_update(self):
        return

    def connect_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("connected")

    def refresh_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("refresh")

    def video_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("video")

    def pid_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("pid")

    def control_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("control")

def run_app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run_app()
```

Comment: Your code works fine, the label updates properly. What's the issue you're facing? Besides that, be aware that modifying a file generated by `pyuic` is considered bad practice (for lots of reasons, most importantly because whenever you need to change the UI you'll have serious problems integrating existing code); I strongly suggest you to follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Also, fixed geometries are never a good idea, and you should use [layout mangers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Specifically, when I run the code file the app will load and the buttons will respond to being moused over; all the controls "work" but the values in the value_boxes are being set to 0.0 and can't go above 100; the internal variables are not getting set for some reason, and clicking the buttons doesn't really do anything for me.

Comment: I don't know what you're exactly trying to achieve, as the code you provided only updates the `x_out_label` label, and your spinboxes correctly have maximum values up to 1000. It usually depends on what the function you're using does; is it possible that it returns a percentage? Unfortunately, unless you provide an actual [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we won't be able to help you more.

Comment: Not really trying to accomplish anything valuable yet; just trying to test my gui before I continue. Not sure what to do when a problem is not reproduceable; it seems to only be an issue on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what was broken, but I rewrote the code using an inherited class to edit my Ui_MainWindow object (as was suggested by musicamante; thank you!) and everything is now working. I am now using the designer generated code unedited, aside from moving the if **main** block to the main file. The working code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import Stewie_UI

class my_window(Stewie_UI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.serial_active = False
        self.cv_active = False
        self.pid_set = False
        self.pid_active = False

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        super().setupUi(MainWindow)

        self.refresh_button.clicked.connect(self.refresh_button_clicked)
        self.connect_button.clicked.connect(self.connect_button_clicked)
        self.video_button.clicked.connect(self.video_button_clicked)
        self.pid_button.clicked.connect(self.pid_button_clicked)
        self.control_button.clicked.connect(self.control_button_clicked)

        self.p_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.p_value_box.setValue(10)

        self.i_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.i_value_box.setValue(10)

        self.d_value_box.setMaximum(1000.0)
        self.d_value_box.setValue(10)

    def perform_update(self):
        return

    def connect_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("connected")

    def refresh_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("refresh")

    def video_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("video")

    def pid_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("pid")

    def control_button_clicked(self):
        self.x_out_label.setText("control")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = my_window()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My designer generated code looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(980, 779)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.refresh_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.refresh_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 640, 93, 30))
        self.refresh_button.setObjectName("refresh_button")
        self.connect_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.connect_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 600, 93, 30))
        self.connect_button.setObjectName("connect_button")
        self.comms_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comms_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 600, 93, 25))
        self.comms_box.setObjectName("comms_box")
        self.video_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.video_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 600, 101, 30))
        self.video_button.setObjectName("video_button")
        self.video_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.video_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 570, 111, 19))
        self.video_title.setObjectName("video_title")
        self.comms_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.comms_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 570, 111, 19))
        self.comms_title.setObjectName("comms_title")
        self.pid_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pid_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 570, 101, 19))
        self.pid_title.setObjectName("pid_title")
        self.x_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 670, 81, 19))
        self.x_label.setObjectName("x_label")
        self.y_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 700, 81, 19))
        self.y_label.setObjectName("y_label")
        self.x_val_out = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_val_out.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 670, 91, 19))
        self.x_val_out.setObjectName("x_val_out")
        self.y_val_out = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_val_out.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 700, 91, 19))
        self.y_val_out.setObjectName("y_val_out")
        self.detected_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.detected_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 640, 111, 19))
        self.detected_label.setObjectName("detected_label")
        self.ball_detected_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ball_detected_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 640, 68, 19))
        self.ball_detected_val.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.ball_detected_val.setObjectName("ball_detected_val")
        self.p_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.p_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 640, 68, 19))
        self.p_label.setObjectName("p_label")
        self.i_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.i_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 670, 68, 19))
        self.i_label.setObjectName("i_label")
        self.d_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.d_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 700, 68, 19))
        self.d_label.setObjectName("d_label")
        self.output_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 570, 121, 19))
        self.output_title.setObjectName("output_title")
        self.x_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.x_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 640, 68, 19))
        self.x_out_label.setObjectName("x_out_label")
        self.p_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.p_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 640, 72, 25))
        self.p_value_box.setObjectName("p_value_box")
        self.i_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.i_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 670, 72, 25))
        self.i_value_box.setObjectName("i_value_box")
        self.d_value_box = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.d_value_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 700, 72, 25))
        self.d_value_box.setObjectName("d_value_box")
        self.pid_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pid_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 600, 93, 30))
        self.pid_button.setObjectName("pid_button")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 640, 160, 20))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider_2 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 670, 160, 20))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_2")
        self.control_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.control_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 600, 101, 30))
        self.control_button.setObjectName("control_button")
        self.y_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.y_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 670, 68, 19))
        self.y_out_label.setObjectName("y_out_label")
        self.pitch_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pitch_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 600, 68, 19))
        self.pitch_label.setObjectName("pitch_label")
        self.roll_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.roll_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 650, 68, 19))
        self.roll_label.setObjectName("roll_label")
        self.pitch_out_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pitch_out_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 620, 68, 19))
        self.pitch_out_val.setObjectName("pitch_out_val")
        self.roll_out_val = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.roll_out_val.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 670, 68, 19))
        self.roll_out_val.setObjectName("roll_out_val")
        self.openGLWidget = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 960, 540))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Stewie Control Page"))
        self.refresh_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))
        self.connect_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.video_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Video"))
        self.video_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Video Controls"))
        self.comms_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Serial Controls"))
        self.pid_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PID Controls"))
        self.x_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X Position:"))
        self.y_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y Position:"))
        self.x_val_out.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Yet Set"))
        self.y_val_out.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Yet Set"))
        self.detected_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ball Detected?:"))
        self.ball_detected_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "No"))
        self.p_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "P:"))
        self.i_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I:"))
        self.d_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D:"))
        self.output_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output Controls"))
        self.x_out_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X_value"))
        self.pid_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set P,I,D"))
        self.control_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Control"))
        self.y_out_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Y_value"))
        self.pitch_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pitch:"))
        self.roll_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Roll:"))
        self.pitch_out_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Set"))
        self.roll_out_val.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Not Set"))
```